# Given a complex function $f(z) = \frac{z^2+3z-5}{z^3}$, find $Res(f,0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I'm working on the question given to me.

Given a complex function $f(z) = \frac{z^2+3z-5}{z^3}$, find $Res(f,0)$.

What I did is I solve first the isolated singularity of $f$ and I found out the isolated singularity $z = 0$ is a pole of order 3.  So I have

$Res(f,0) = \frac{1}{(3-1)!}\frac{d^2}{dz^2} \left( z^3 f(z)\right)_{z=0} = 1/2(2) = 1$.

Am I correct? Or is anybody can point out a mistake here? I really much appreciate it.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you're correct

Comment: To be really technical, $f(z)$ is not defined when $z=0$, so it's evaluated as $z\to0$

Comment: Thank you, @J.W.Tanner. I really appreciate it

Comment: A simpler way: $f(z)=\frac1 z+\frac  3{z^{2}}-\frac 5 {z^{3}}$ and the residue is simply the coefficient of $\frac 1 z$.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you so much @KaviRamaMurthy